# gcc fails to find reference to object in dynamic library

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm trying to use the FFT code from the libav library. As the code is LGPL I need to link it as a dynamic library, but the linker can't seem to resolve some symbols:

```
gcc -g -fPIC fft-test.c -I. -L. -lavutil -lavcodec -lm -o fft_test
```

Gives me the following error:

```
fft-test.c:319: undefined reference to `ff_fft_init'
```

But linking with the .a version of the library works fine:

```
gcc -g -fPIC fft-test.c -I. -L. -lavutil -l:libavcodec.a -lm -o fft_test
```

objdump for the libavcodec.so file shows that ff_fft_init is defined:

```
000000000002f146 l     F .text  0000000000000229              ff_fft_init
```

objdump for the .a version looks fine as well:

```
00000000000000ed g     F .text.unlikely 0000000000000229 ff_fft_init
```

I've tried swapping the order of the libraries in my link command as well as using the `-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group` options. No luck.

So what am I missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: have you forgotten the #include in fft-test.c?

Comment: Definitely included. However, the fft.h header file plays some strange games:
`#define FFT_NAME(x) x`
`#define ff_fft_init FFT_NAME(ff_fft_init)`
`int ff_fft_init(FFTContext *s, int nbits, int inverse);`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want PIC for your binary? Does the linker behave differently without `-fPIC` when you link against the .so file?

Comment: Ultimately the code that will actually call this fft shared library is also a shared library. The -fPIC switch doesn't have any effect here.

Comment: Sorry forgot the @HonkyTonk for that last comment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is an answer but it might help you.

I wrote a minimal compilable example:

```
#include <libavcodec/fft.h>

int main(int argc, int* argv[]) {
  ff_fft_init(NULL, 0, 0);

  return 0;
}
```

and I compile it in the root folder of a newly compiled `ffmpeg-2.0.1` source code bundle:

`$ gcc fft-test.c -I. -Llibavcodec -Llibavutil -lavcodec -lavutil -lm -o fft_test`

And it works as one would expect:

```
$ ls -al fft_test 
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 foo foo 451859 Sep 14 10:49 fft_test
```

So, I'd suggest trying to trim your existing code down to something minimal and when you get it to compile, slowly add the rest piece by piece to see where it breaks.

Comment: Yes that does help, but probably not how you expected. The ffmpeg code doesn't have this problem.